# Android Studio 4.1 Beta Start Failed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I previously downloaded Android Studio 4.1 Beta 5 and it was working just fine, but when I launch it today, this error is showing:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.AssertionError: Attribute 
id='AUTO_DETECTION_CACHE_ATTRIBUTE' is not unique
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1643)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:193)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Attribute id='AUTO_DETECTION_CACHE_ATTRIBUTE' is not unique
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.FileAttribute.<init>(FileAttribute.java:34)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.<init>(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:159)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at.....

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio 4.1 Beta\jre\jre
```

What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487696/android-studio-4-1-rc-facing-start-failed-error-after-upgrade) This is the link I found, hope it is useful to you