# Android Studio 4.1 RC, facing start failed error after upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio

After update Android Studio 4.1 RC, I getting this issue,

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\{AndroidStudioPATH}\jre\jre
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64709612/5033247

Answer (score 52):

please remove the file .local/share/google and Open android studio it will work

Comment: where i find this file?

Comment: @Arbaz.in this folder exists in the ~/.local/share folder. check it

Comment: Does it affect anything at all? Any setting, Git credentials...?
And how to do it on Windows?

Comment: @androiddeveloper it affect only on android studio configs (settings and etc). you can find `Google` folder in `%appdata%` path in windows.

Comment: can't find it on Mac. What is the path in mac?

Comment: @HamidSj i found it actully was hidden.

Comment: @AlonShlider did you find this path in your mac?

Comment: @AlonShlider See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354776/3422470

Comment: what is the reason behind this? why would removing that file help solve the issue?

Comment: Can also be `.local/share/Google`

Comment: I cannot find .local/share/google in Windows. Where is this file?

Comment: It might be some plugin related issues, after removing all plugins Android studio worked fine at my side.
For Windows: C:\Users\{user.name}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Remove all files in the plugins folder. Enjoy

Answer (score 38):

Rename the `marketplace` folder to `marketplace_back` which is located in

- **Ubuntu at,** `.local/share/google`
- **Windows at** `%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio4.1\config\plugins\` or `%AppData%\Roaming\Google`.
  Version number may change if you are updated.
- **Mac at**  `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins`
- **Pop OS**  `~/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio`

Comment: Worked for windows 10

Comment: The problem has solved by replacing name but why this happened?

Comment: For Pop!_OS the location is `~/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio`. I just renamed that folder and it started working again. Good luck!

Comment: %USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio4.1\config\plugins\ contains a marketplace folder which we can delete or rename to make it work.

Answer (score 36):

For **MacOS**, navigate to the directory: `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio`

Delete the `marketplace` folder or rename it to `marketplace_back`

I noticed that I had some plugin issues after this change so there may be a better way to do this but at least I'm now able to open Android Studio.

Comment: This is the only plugin I needed to delete as well and my error went away.  On Windows the path was `C:\Users\{user}\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins\marketplace`

Answer (score 33):

Issue solved: Problem is there on plugins, one of my plugin it's not supporting to latest android studio, So I checked all my application plugin paths.

```
%appdata%/google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

or
full path : `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Google`
or
path : `C:\Users\{USER}\.AndroidStudio4.1\config\plugins`

then I opened plugins folder then selected all plugins moved to some other location. then opened studio. I observed no issue to open.

if you need plugins, copy plugin into plugins folder one by one, then open studio. if successfully opened that plugin supported else unsupported.

Comment: Help for ubuntu , i update to 4.1 but cant find .androidStudio4.1 i only have previous version 3.0 and 4.0 folder issue is same as above

Comment: @babbintandukar please remove the file   .local/share/google and Open android studio it will work

Comment: @Subratsss i think your solution should work the problem was android wifi adb was not supported in 4.1 
though i learned it hard way i opened it from root and updated it again then it worked

Comment: Does it affect anything at all? Any setting, Git credentials...?

Comment: No way affect your old setting or setup

Comment: @babbintandukar can you please further explain what you did?

Comment: @Andrey i opened the AS from path iteself using sudo ./studio.sh it starts the as with your previous setting  mine it opened AS 4.0 .after that i updated from here then it worked fine

Comment: Worked for me. Just removing the marketplace folder is enough.

Answer (score 13):

**For Ubuntu users**

1. go to `home`
2. press `ctrl+h` to show hidden folder `.local`
3. now go to `.local` folder
4. you will find `share` folder, go inside `share` folder
5. find `Google` folder and delete it
6. Open `Android Studio`
7. **Voila !!!**

Comment: Thanks i am looking for the same found that folder and deleted now it's working.

Comment: this folder contains all your plugins so make sure to copy them to the new generated one.

Comment: Great Explanation.

Comment: Delete only marketplace plugin:  rm -rf ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/*.plugins/market*

Answer (score 12):

**No need to delete the *Google* folder**

Go to .local/share/google  (**ubuntu** press **ctrl+h** in HOME)

Just Rename **marketplace** to **marketplace_back**

And Restart Android Studio.

Comment: how does it work on mac os 10.15? I can't find the google folder on local/share/

Comment: @ajay See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354776/3422470

Answer (score 11):

**For Windows Users:**

Go to

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins
```

Replace `marketplace` to `marketplace_back`.

Start Android Studio Now.

This should work fine!

Answer (score 5):

I deleted all the xxxx.plugins folders inside this folder:

> %appdata%\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0

[image: Folders to delete. There could be multiple.]
Then it started perfectly. And, also asked me to download missing components for SDK.
[image: Installing Missing Components]

Answer (score 5):

Just delete this folder, it works for me:

C:\Users"user"\AppData\Roaming\Google

Answer (score 2):

In my case deleting the `plugins` folder under `C:\Users\{USER}\.AndroidStudio4.0\config` did it. After starting android studio the folder will be created it again:

[image]

Make a copy of the folder just in case something happends.

Answer (score 1):

For windows Usesr -

you just need to remove 1 file from your file manager

1. Goto to path -
   C:\Users{you user name}.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins.
2. remove folder name "marketplace".

restart your android studio.

Answer (score 1):

If the android studio files are moved to another location ([Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place/63868816#63868816))
then look for **idea.properties** file
In my case above file contents were

```
idea.config.path=E:/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/config
idea.system.path=E:/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/system
```

I renamed **marketplace** folder (`E:\Android\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins\marketplace`) and hurray android studio started working.

Comment: From what to what renamed

Comment: the existing marketplace folder is causing the issue. Either you can delete that folder or rename to anything else of your choice. I suggest rename because once deleted you may not get it back.

Answer (score 0):

for win10，you can：

1，open path C:\Users{here is your user name}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

2,rename folder 'markerplace' to 'markerplace_backup'

3,launcher android studio

4,rename 'markerplace_backup' to 'markerplace'

5,check updates and update plugin.

is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the marketplace renaming and the plugins deletion, neither worked. So I downgraded my SDK, downloading the earlier version of Android Studio made everything work.

Answer (score 0):

If someone had used *JetBrains Toolbox* for downloading android studio, the marketplace folder located at

`/home/{user}/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.7042882.plugins/marketplace`

Delete that folder and it should work.