# Android Studio Error after updating to Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating my Android Studio 4.0 to Android Studio 4.1 getting this error

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.1 RC, facing start failed error after upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487696/android-studio-4-1-rc-facing-start-failed-error-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using the following steps:

1. close android studio
2. Deleting the .AndroidStudio4.0 folder from the following path
   "C:\Users\my_user_name"
3. Run Android studio and it will download components again

That's all worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I Updated my Android Studio as well and had the same problem.

I Fixed removing the marketplace folder inside *C:\Users\USER\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins*

Comment: i solved by removing android studio and installing from scratch

Comment: For Ubuntu: please remove the file .local/share/google and Open android studio it will work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the files inside:
*C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins\marketplace\lib*

It's safer copy the files to another location before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the **AndroidStudio4.0** folder from

- "C:\Users\my_user_name" and
- "C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google"

did not work for me. What I did was to delete the **AndroidStudio4.1** in the second path as well and the error was solved for me.