# Android Studio 4.1 updates gives internal error and can't start

Tags: android-studio

I have checked the newly opened threads about the issue but none fixed the problem

[image]

I am using a mac and I don't understand what should I delete to make it work. Or should I just completely delete the IDE and freshly reinstall it?

Comment: What is your OS version? It seems that you need to update your OS

Comment: Unless you know exactly "what changed", it sounds like the quickest/surest solution might be to reinstall ;)  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64329406/421195: `remove the file .local/share/google`

Comment: Where did you get Android studio? Did you use its internal update mechanism or downloaded a dmg ?

Comment: 1) My OS if the latest version 2) I updated the IDE from inside the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Android studio 4.1 on Linux Mint 19.3 after update had the same error.

Some of the plugins(Marketplace and Makrdown) are not compatible with the new version.

Some suggestions were to delete /.local/share/google(but there was no such folder on Linux Mint 19.3)

I solved it by renaming(or deleting) marketplace plugin folder in /home/user/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/data/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

After that Andorid Studio starts normal and plugins can be udated.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted and reinstalled the IDE and it works fine.

Google should really check their releases before going out official - If I were to work on an important project this would waste many hours for nothing.