# Android Studio crashes on startup (64 bit, Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio

Each attempt to start Android Studio gets the same results -

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

I've re-installed - same error.
I've uninstalled, removed .gradle and .AndroidStudio4.0 folders, reinstalled - same error.

Any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-5051 seems relevant

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487696/android-studio-4-1-rc-facing-start-failed-error-after-upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I solved this then hard way.  Completely uninstalled any and all Android Studio(s), cleared out any relevant folders and re-installed Studio.
Took most of the day but I can once again update my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete or rename marketplace folder in android studio

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Google
```